# Lists custom taxonomy terms that has specific custom field value assigned to the term (not post)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, terms

As title reads, I am trying to list specific custom tax's terms in a custom post type archive's page.

---

**My setup:**

Custom post type: 'podcast'

Custom Taxonomy: 'showname'

-> Custom Field for above taxonomy term: 'language' (ACF Select)

---

**Desired Output**

EN:

Term Name 1 thats custom field 'language' = 'EN'

Term Name 2 thats custom field 'language' = 'EN'

FR:

Term Name 3 thats custom field 'language' = 'FR'

Term Name 4 thats custom field 'language' = 'FR'
.....

---

I have limited languages so if I can somehow just get a result for a single language, I can run multiple loops.

Thanks

Comment: This is specific to the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, and would be more appropriate on their support forum, 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here.